# How to copy from one buffer to another in gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to copy from the original buffer `buf` (in the `chain` function) to another buffer created using:

```
GstBuffer *buffer;
glong size;

size = GST_BUFFER_SIZE(buf);
buffer = gst_buffer_new ();
GST_BUFFER_SIZE (buffer) = size;
GST_BUFFER_MALLOCDATA (buffer) = g_malloc (size);
GST_BUFFER_DATA (buffer) = GST_BUFFER_MALLOCDATA (buffer);
memcpy(buffer,buf,size);
```

But I get a segmentation fault. Is there anything wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than writing to the data the `GstBuffer` is managing, you're overwriting the `GstBuffer` object itself with your final `memcpy` call.  Instead, you want to write to `GST_BUFFER_DATA (buffer)`.

With that said if you just want a new buffer with the same data, it would seem easier to just use the `gst_buffer_copy()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
GstBuffer *buffer;
glong size;
size = GST_BUFFER_SIZE(inp);
buffer = gst_buffer_new();
GST_BUFFER_SIZE(buffer) = size;
GST_BUFFER_MALLOCDATA(buffer) = g_malloc(size);
GST_BUFFER_DATA(buffer) = GST_BUFFER_MALLOCDATA(buffer);
buffer = GST_BUFFER_DATA(inp);
```

// Now you can use the data pointed by buffer to say write it in a file using fwrite